# When searching twice pressing enter in the quickfix windows doesn't work

Tags: vim, ack

I'm on MacVim and I'm using the ack plugin for searching `.vimrc`

```
Plug 'mileszs/ack.vim'
let g:ackprg = 'ag --vimgrep --smart-case'
```

When I type `:Ack search_term` **the first time after opening vim**, the quickfix window pops up, the search results are highlighted and when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a new buffer is opened with the cursor at the position of the search result.

When I don't close the quickfix window, I can search again and everything works fine.

However when I close the quickfix window with `:bd!` and search again, the quickfix window will open, but the search results are not highlighted and when I press enter it doesn't open a new buffer (it just sets the cursor one line below).

This happened after I recently updated my MacVim to `Custom Version 8.1.950 (155)`. I already updated all my plugins but nothing seems to change.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I believe that is a regression, that has been fixed by patch [8.1.988](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/4056)